# settings say sqlite, connection says postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-7

[image: server error]

[image: database settings point to sqlite]

Trying to figure out whats the deal with this.

Im using rails 7.0. Used rails a while back so not really too sure what im doing wrong.

The settings show its all pointing to Sqlite but its trying to connect to postgres.

I havent changed anything, rails new my_app and this is what I got.

Comment: I assume you've tried stopping/starting the rails server? Can you confirm the path of the `database.yml` file is `config/databaselyml`? What happens when you do `rails db` or try to access the db from the console (e.g. `rails c` and then something like `User.last`).

Comment: Please don't post images of code. [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @melcher It gives the same problem. It tries to connect to a non-existing postgres service

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have the `pg` gem in your Gemfile and not the `sqlite` gem. Fix that and it will work.

Comment: I have both pg and sqlite in my Gemfile. How do I use the sqlite library instead of pg. Doesnt seem obvious at first

Comment: It should be either pg or sqlite, not both. Remove the pg gem, `bundle install` and try again

Comment: So my deployment worked. rails was looking to connect to postgres that it could not connect to because I had an ENV var DATABASE_URL set. Once this was removed, it was trying to connect to sqlite as desired. Thanks again